# Calculating mutual information in python returns nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan, information-theory

I've implemented the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) formula in python using `pandas` and `numpy`

```
def mutual_info(p):
    p_x=p.sum(axis=1)
    p_y=p.sum(axis=0)
    I=0.0
    for i_y in p.index:
        for i_x in p.columns:
           I+=(p.ix[i_y,i_x]*np.log2(p.ix[i_y,i_x]/(p_x[i_y]*p[i_x]))).values[0]
    return I
```

However, if a cell in `p` has a zero probability, then `np.log2(p.ix[i_y,i_x]/(p_x[i_y]*p[i_x]))` is negative infinity, and the whole expression is multiplied by zero and returns `NaN`.

What is the right way to work around that?

Comment: Can't you check if there's a zero in p and in that case return the value you expect for this case?

Comment: I have no idea what is the entropy of zero probability

Comment: perhaps someone here knows

Comment: Well then maybe nan is a good return value until you know? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For various theoretical and practical reasons (e.g., see [Competitive Distribution Estimation:
Why is Good-Turing Good](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5762-competitive-distribution-estimation-why-is-good-turing-good.pdf)), you might consider *never* using a zero probability with the log loss measure.

So, say, if you have a probability vector *p*, then, for some small scalar *α > 0*, you would use *α 1 + (1 - α) p* (where here the first 1 is the uniform vector). Unfortunately, there are no general guidelines for choosing *α*, and you'll have to assess this further down the calculation.

For the Kullback-Leibler distance, you would of course apply this to each of the inputs.